# How to post photo to Timeline Photos via Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook graph API to upload photo on Facebook.
=> That's OK.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
          $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
            'source' => new CURLFile('upload/bg-design.jpg', 'image/png'),
            'message' => 'Hello world',
            'caption'=> 'Day la caption'
          )
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

But it's always upload to XXXXXXX album (base on facebook app_ID).

Everybody has solution to post photo on Timeline Photos?

Answer (score 3):

Just take a look there:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album/photos#publish

You are not using the right api call currently if you want to be able to post your picture in a specific album.

Comment: You're welcome. Please put my answer as a good one (button under vote down).

Comment: Sorry, I have not enough reputation to vote for you :(